# How does Ubuntu version upgrade works (technically)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, package-management, development

I know that when I update my packages (programs, kernel, etc) it syncs from the repository and if there is a newer version updates to it. I think that OS updates are the same, however I don't know exactly what packages or files are they changing (for example when upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 what happens exactly in the background?).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409555/what-does-do-release-upgrade-really-do

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And excuse me, I didn't notice that thread before.